# Vala: calling super class creation method at constructor

Tags: vala

I have been trying to initialize a parent class using it's creation method.

```
class A {
    public A.creator (int x, int y) {
        // do some magic
    }
}

class B : A {
    public B.creator (int x, int y) {
        // I want to do something like
        base.creator (x, y);
    }
}
```

I am facing an error while trying to run the above code.

`error: chain up to 'A.creator' not supported`

What's the correct way to accomplish this in vala?

Comment: Which vala version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

When I try to compile your code I get:

```
chain.vala:1.1-1.7: error: Class name `A' is too short
class A {
^^^^^^^
chain.vala:7.1-7.11: error: Class name `B' is too short
class B : A {
^^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

After renaming `A` to `Aaa` and `B` to `Bbb` the code compiles just fine with valac 0.36.15.

My first thought was that you might have to derive `A` from `Object`, but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: [From the Vala mailing list (2009)](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/vala-list/2009-July/msg00100.html), i quote: "I'm not familiar with the reasoning behind the restriction, however,
it's a limit of GObject, not a limit of Vala. We just report the error
in Vala to avoid a runtime error from GObject later on."

Comment: Interesting. Too bad the error message does not state any reason why the class name is too short.

Comment: Yes, indeed. And it does not distinguish between classes that inherit from GObject or other types like GType or compact to which that restriction probably won't apply. However, short names should be avoided.